# Delete SSIS Job Programmatically On Completion

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS job that I have created with a single job step (all done programatically in C#) that I want to delete after it is completed. Is there a way to do this? I was thinking I might have to run a new job step on success of the first job step that deletes the job it's associated with but I don't know the command to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean a SQL Server Agent job that runs an SSIS package?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

By SSIS Job do you mean that your executing an SSIS Package via a SQL Job? If you're needing to remove a SQL Job you can use sp_delete_job stored procedure in SQL Server. It can be found in the MSDB database.